# How does scanf handle white space?

Tags: c, string

I am new to Cstring, sorry for asking dumb question, please help.

```
char string[10];

printf("Give me your last name:\n");
scanf ("%s", string);                   //if i type 123 123
printf("Original string:%s\n", string);  //it shows 123
```

Compare to:

```
char string[] = "123 123";

printf("Original string:%s\n", string);  //it shows 123 123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right behaviour. By default `scanf` reads the string until it reaches a whitespace.

From `scanf` manpage:

> s
>    Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters;
>    the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough
>    to hold the input sequence and  the  terminating
>    null character ('\0'), which is added automatically.
>    The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width,
>    whichever occurs first.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is scanf. When you use scanf with %s it reads until it hits whitespace.
To read the entire line you may want to consider using [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).

Comment: Never, NEVER use `gets()`. Use `fgets()` or `getline()` instead.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII How come?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Why is that?

Comment: @Carl Buffer overrun. `gets` reads arbitrary length input, which is extremely dangerous. You cannot ensure that your buffer has enough capacity to handle the input.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` treats space as the end of the string.
So it stops reading once it encounters a `space` character.

While in case of c style array `\0` is considered the end of the array.
When you initialize,

```
char string[] = "123 123";
```

A `\0` is implicitly added at the end of 7th character `3`, and it marks the end of this array.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` scans for a string until any whitespace. If you need to read until a newline, then use `fgets()`:

```
char string[64];
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

printf("%s", string); // should now contain any whitespace in the string.
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `gets()` also creates some warnings. If you are so determined to use `scanf()`, you can use it like `scanf("%[^\n]", character_array_variable);`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char FullName[20];

    scanf("%[^\n]s",FullName);

    printf("%s",FullName);
}
```

The output image:
[image: The output image]

Answer (score 1):

What you see here happens due to the way `scanf()` works. You can print strings with any character inside (no matter whether it's a whitespace or not). `scanf()` just stops once it encounters a whitespace as it considers this variable "done".