# sscanf ignoring spaces in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
char s[20] = "test1 16 test2";
char a[20]; char b[20];
sscanf(s, "%s%*d%s", a, b);
printf("'%s' '%s'", a, b); //'test1' 'test2'
```

Is sscanf preprogrammed to ignore whitespaces?
I was expecting :

```
'test1 ' ' test2'.
```

Comment: "until the first whitespace character" this means excluded i guess. thank you.

Comment: Yes, except for `%c` and `%[]`.

Comment: there's no way of reading the whitespace?

Comment: oh by adding %c

Comment: isn't it possible to include the whitespace inside the string directly from the sscanf?

Comment: Usually the next whitespace is filtered out by the *next* `sscanf` call.

Comment: As I wrote, with `%[]`.

Comment: yes [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1247989/995714), [How do I read in white spaces with scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14995058/995714), [How does scanf handle white space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9958000/995714)...

Comment: Did you mean `'test1 ' ' test2'` as your expected output?

Comment: @WeatherVane that's reading the entire line and bypassing the other arguments, I tried %6[]%*d%s it only reads the first part.

Comment: What's wrong with `" %5[^\n]%d%s"`?  (How did you get `6` as the *field-width* modifier? -- unless you want the space at the end of `test1` and before `test2`, then use `" %6[^\n]%d%[^\n]"`) Remove the leading `" ..."` to read *leading-whitespace*.

Comment: As they say, please read the manual. With `%[]` you specify the terminating character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the spaces in the scanned strings, the `%n` specifier, to capture the number of characters processed by the scan, may be the better choice. `"%s %n` will record the number of characters processed by the first word and the trailing whitespace. `%*d%n` will scan and discard the integer and record the total number of characters processed to the end of the integer. Then `%s%n` will skip the whitespace and scan the last word and record the total number of characters processed.
Use `strncpy` to copy the word and whitespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 19
//so SIZE can be part of sscanf Format String
#define FS_(x) #x
#define FS(x) FS_(x)


int main ( void) {
    char s[SIZE + 1] = "test1 16 test2";
    char a[SIZE + 1]; char b[SIZE + 1];
    int before = 0;
    int after = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    if ( 2 == sscanf(s, "%"FS(SIZE)"s %n%*d%n%"FS(SIZE)"s%n", a, &before, &after, b, &stop)) {
        if ( before <= SIZE) {
            strncpy ( a, s, before);//copy before number of characters
            a[before] = 0;//terminate
        }
        if ( stop - after <= SIZE) {
            strncpy ( b, &s[after], stop - after);//from index after, copy stop-after characters
            b[stop - after] = 0;//terminate
        }
        printf("'%s' '%s'\n", a, b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```